# TuriCreate Install Issues

Tags: python, turi-create

I am having some issues with installing TuriCreate in my virtual environment. I have the following versions:

- ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Python 3.10.12
- pip 24.0

I updated my setuptools wheel versions and still getting this error:

```
(venv) colter@MSI:~$ pip install turicreate
Collecting turicreate
  Using cached turicreate-6.4.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: turicreate
  Building wheel for turicreate (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [44 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      /home/colter/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
              standards-based tools.

              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
      running install



              ==================================================================================
              TURICREATE ERROR

              If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
              for your system.

              Supported Platforms:
                  * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
                  * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).

              Support Python Versions:
                  * 2.7
                  * 3.5
                  * 3.6
                  * 3.7
                  * 3.8

              Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try:
                  `pip install -U pip`

              ==================================================================================



      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for turicreate
  Running setup.py clean for turicreate
Failed to build turicreate
ERROR: Could not build wheels for turicreate, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Can someone please support? Thank you!!

I have the following versions:

- ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Python 3.10.12
- pip 24.0

I updated my setuptools wheel versions and latest Python, and latest PIP.

Comment: The error message already did support: `Support Python Versions: * 2.7 * 3.5 * 3.6 * 3.7 * 3.8`. Is the one you have one of them?

Comment: Thats why I am confused, I have the supporting Python version.

Comment: No, you have 3.10, that's not one of them?!

Comment: lol, I thought for some reason it supported 3.10, my mistake!

Comment: The answer here did not solve my problem, still getting the same errors. Anyone else have any other ideas? I have python 3.8 on my system and have set it as priority to use in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

turicreate supports macOS 10.12+, Linux (with glibc 2.12+) Windows 10 (via WSL) and requires Python 2.7, 3.5 - 3.8. There's no support for your Python 3.10.12.

Please downgrade your python to a supported version and then `pip install turicreate` to use this package. It is recommended to use virtual environments to handle this.

See https://pypi.org/project/turicreate/

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.... I error out wiht the "Building wheel for truicreate (setup.py) . . ." ERROR: Failed building wheel for turicreate

Comment: I also perform the sudo apt and unistall 3.10.12, then sudo install 3.8. After it successfully installs, I verify what version I have and it tells me 3.10.12..... am I not installing or uninstalling correctly?

Comment: Perhaps, see the link for how to install multiple versions of Python on Ubuntu https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-and-switch-python-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: Unfortunately, this still didnt work :/